# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\exists \ \ b \in \mathbb{R} : f(x+b)=\sqrt{f(x)-f^2(x)}+\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: limits, functional-equations, periodic-functions

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\exists  \ \ b \in \mathbb{R} : f(x+b)=\sqrt{f(x)-f^2(x)}+\frac{1}{2}$
>   then find the :
>
> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=?$$

My Try : $f^2(x+b)+\frac{1}{4}-f(x+b)=f(x)-f^2(x)$
and let $b=0$ then $f^2(x)+\frac{1}{4}-f(x)=f(x)-f^2(x)$ so $b \neq 0$

now what do i do ?

Comment: What are the assumption on $f$ continuity existence of the limit is assumed please clrify

Comment: Since you've asked below both the answers, I'll tell you why $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = l$. To most limit questions, there are two parts: 1) "Does it converge?", and 2) "If it does, to what value does it converge?" Now, logically, you ought to do number 1 first. However, it is often easier to do 2 first, since once have proven something along the lines of "If it converges, it has to converge to $0.72$", it becomes a lot easier to either prove or disprove that it converges at all. That's why a lot of answers start with "Assume the limit is $L$" before they've even checked whether it converges.

Comment: @Arthur You're right. However, two answers given so far do not even mention the question 1) exists, let alone trying to answer it.

Comment: @CiaPan It is true that in our quest to find the limit in 2, we often forget 1. That is wrong, but it's a very easy mistake to make.

Comment: @Arthur (Adding just for completeness) Both answers I mentioned above turned out wrong, just due to neglecting 1); and both get deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite the starting equation like this:

$$\left(f(x+b)-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2={1\over 4}-{1\over 4}+{f(x)-f^2(x)}= {1\over 4}- \left(f(x)-{1\over 2}\right)^2$$

so we have also

$$\left(f(x)-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2= {1\over 4}- \left(f(x-b)-{1\over 2}\right)^2$$

Combining both equations we get $$\left(f(x+b)-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \left(f(x-b)-{1\over 2}\right)^2$$
and so $$\left|f(x+b)-\frac{1}{2}\right| = \left|f(x-b)-{1\over 2}\right|$$

But $f(x)\geq 1/2$ for all $x$ so we have $$f(x+b)-\frac{1}{2} = f(x-b)-{1\over 2}$$

which means that $f$ is periodic with period $2b$ and thus the limit doesn't exist unless $f$ is constant.

Comment: This was what I was going to write

Comment: Yes christian it is complete correct, great work!!